# Email MSBuild errors - only when there are errors

Tags: msbuild, msbuildcommunitytasks

```
 msbuild MyProject.proj /fl /flp:v=detailed;logfile=mylog.txt
 msbuild MyProject.proj /t:ErrorEmail
```

I have implemented this, and it works when there are errors. 
But it's also sending an email when there are no errors. 
How can I set up a condition if the file is empty, or there are 0 line count in the ReadLinesFromFile?

```
> <Target Name="ErrorEmail">    
>   <ReadLinesFromFile
>       File="mylog.txt"
>       Lines="_ErrorLines"
>       />
>   <MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Mail
>       SmtpServer="mailhost.amsa.com"
>       To="$(ErrorEmails)"
>       From="$(FromEmail)"
>       Subject="Build failure for $(SolutionName)" 
>       Body="Error details: @(ErrorFileContents, '%0D%0A')"
>       />
>  </Target>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming *ErrorFileContents* is not empty in case of an error, you can iterate through its items to set a condition flag.

```
   <CreateProperty Value="true">
      <Output Condition="'%(ErrorFileContents.Identity)' != ''"
          TaskParameter="Value"
          PropertyName="SendMail" />
    </CreateProperty>

    <MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Mail Condition="'$(SendMail)' == true"
        SmtpServer="mailhost.amsa.com"
        To="$(ErrorEmails)"
        From="$(FromEmail)"
        Subject="Build failure for $(SolutionName)"
        Body="Error details: @(ErrorFileContents, '%0D%0A')"
       />
```

Comment: Is CreateProperty a 4.0 feature?  I'm on 3.5 and get this error: "The element <CreateProperty> beneath element <Project> is unrecognized"

Comment: Ah - looks like it has to be under a target.